# Is it appropriate to post vim questions on Stack Overflow now that there is a vi/vim site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There have been many other questions about whether it is appropriate to post vim/vi questions on Stack Overflow, but now that the [vim/vi Stack Exchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com) site is in beta, is it still appropriate?  I have seen several comments on vim/vi questions saying

> Shouldn't this be on the vim/vi site?

I know that there are also a lot of vim related questions scattered across [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Super User](http://superuser.com), and the [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com) as well; is it just a matter of preferance?

Comment: It is a beta site, it doesn't get a lot of traffic.  Whether it survives is up in the air.  If you *like* the idea of a dedicated site that will only speak VIM then by all means, use it.  You probably won't get the typical 10 minute-or-less SO turnaround, YMMV.  It is up to you.

Comment: @HansPassant is right about the slower turn-around time, but I would also like to say that some questions have gotten significantly better answers than what's on SO. Disclaimer: I am biased since I wrote a number of those answers, but judge for yourself. For example, compare [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2162/why-doesnt-the-backspace-key-work-in-insert-mode?s=1|0.8535) to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11560201/660921), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10727392/660921), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5019315/660921) ...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is possible for questions to be on topic on two sites.  I happens from time to time.  You get it with SO and gamedev/unix&linux (and ubuntu)/apple/programmers/computer science and probably some others that I've missed too in that.  It happens.  Now there's a 'vi' site, and yes, questions could be asked there instead.

Note that Stack Overflow's charter as described in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is:

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

For some questions vi, it would be on topic here (things about programming macros).  Probably things about getting certain syntax highlighting or integration with ctags working would be too.  However, it would be on topic on VI.SE also.

Questions about use of vi from a non-programming aspect though, would not be on topic here.  Note that "unique to software development" part in the on topic definition.  If the question is not unique to software development, it is off topic here (and has always been so).

These questions would be things like "how to diff two files" or "how to split the window vertically in vi?" or the like.  And those would probably be better asked on VI.SE than on SO.

If you look at the front page of VI.SE you see questions that are nearly entirely questions of use:

- [Entering search pattern with syntax highlighting?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2283/entering-search-pattern-with-syntax-highlighting)
- [How to write vertically?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/how-to-write-vertically)
- [Re-indenting badly indented code](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/236/re-indenting-badly-indented-code)
- [How can I create a pseudo insert mode with a different keymap?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/how-can-i-create-a-pseudo-insert-mode-with-a-different-keymap)

And so on.  Of those, only the Re-indenting badly indented code appears to be a question that is on topic on Stack Overflow.

---

So... you've got a question that would be appropriate on both sites.

First off, ***do not cross post the question***.  This is seen as incredibly rude on some stack exchange sites. You can read more about my feelings on this on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243851/213963)

The choice of Stack Overflow vs another site has some significant differences.  Smaller sites are much less likely to get a 10 minute answer, but they are more likely to get the longer and more complete answers.

Furthermore, Stack Overflow's front page (for me) is about 5 hours old with significant filtering that SE does to try to get the interesting questions.  New questions on SO is about 9 minutes for 50/page.  VI.SE has received 50 questions in the past week.  This means your question lasts in the (much less intense) light for much longer on VI.SE than on SO.

I'm going to point out that at the time of this writing VI.SE has 377 questions.  The [vi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vi) tag on Stack Overflow has 1,177 questions.  Thats not bad for how fast questions are getting asked on VI.SE rather than on SO.  The [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) has quite a few more at just over 16k as of this writing.  A cursory glance there suggests that a reasonable portion of these questions are about usage and are things that one might flag for migration given that they are new enough.

---

Choose the site that most likely has the experts you want to answer your question and ask there.

You can make people aware of the VI.SE site, but please don't encourage that people *repost* a question on VI.SE.

If a vi question is off topic here, consider flagging (this would be a custom flag - it is not one of the standard migration paths for Stack Overflow - explain in detail why the question is off topic on SO, on topic on VI.SE, and a good question) it for migration to VI.SE rather than suggesting reposting.  Given the nature of SO, there's likely an answer on the question here before it can get closed as off topic.  It would be best to keep the answers together (and move it to a site where it is on topic) than to have copies of the questions with differing answers across the SE network.

Comment: "*VI.SE has 377 questions. The vi tag on Stack Overflow has 1,177 questions. Thats not bad for how fast questions are getting asked on VI.SE rather than on SO.*" -> The [tag:vim] tag on SO has 16,147 questions :-)

Comment: Thank you... too often I see people arguing topicality based on "software tools commonly used by programmers" alone, without considering that it is conjoined to "unique to software development" by an AND, not an OR.

Comment: "consider flagging it for migration to VI.SE" since VI.SE is not included in the normal off-topic migration list, you'll need to use a custom flag to do this migration.

Comment: I was going to upvote because of mentioning cats, but now I have to downvote because they've been removed.

Comment: I think diffing text files is more of a programmer-ey task than not. I'd encourage tolerance for these posts on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JeremyBanks There is a continuum between "only on vi.se" and "only on so". Diffing is probably in the middle there.. and while programmers do it a lot, it is not something that is unique to programming (I've seen tech writers do it, and worked with a person doing translations in a properties file for localization - neither of which are programmers). This isn't to say "all vi questions off SO", but rather that there are other places and questions such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28813521/) may be things that can be migrated and are of questionable on-topicness on SO.