# Correct place to ask programming-related testing questions?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

I just found out that there is [SQA](http://sqa.stackexchange.com), a Stack Exchange site that deals with quality assurance and testing. At the moment there are [20 questions](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=silktest) dealing with SilkTest over there. On the other hand side, Stack Overflow even has a tag [silktest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/silktest) with 52 questions.

The SQA tour says I should ask about

> Specific issues with software quality assurance or testing
>       Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

which could apply to programming issues (e.g. with SilkTest here) as well.

Should I start asking programming related SilkTest questions on SQA or should I stick to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Their meta seems to have similar questions, [this one](http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/205/can-we-use-programming-questions-to-teach-defect-isolation) and [this one about selenium](http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/295/what-are-our-standards-about-selenium-questions)

Comment: This is about a different in-beta SE site, but it's relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287089/is-it-appropriate-to-post-vim-questions-on-stack-overflow-now-that-there-is-a-vi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its actually *programming related* (ie, there's some code involved), then ask here. If that overlaps SQA, so be it, you can ask either place.

If its purely related to *using* the software, or other aspects of software testing that aren't programming, then ask there, not here.