# Are vi/Vim questions now off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

While going reviewing the close votes queue on vi.se, I ran across [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13236/unable-to-delete-old-characters-after-upgrading-to-vim-8-0), which was closed as off-topic and migrated to vi.se, where it's been flagged as a dupe. According to this [meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287089/is-it-appropriate-to-post-vim-questions-on-stack-overflow-now-that-there-is-a-vi) on vi/Vim, they are on-topic. Has this changed, or was it an error?

To clarify, this is the only question I've seen migrated from Stack Overflow to the vi Stack Exchange, as long as I've been a member of either site.

Comment: As counter intuitive as it may sound, people may vote based on the title *Are vi/vim questions now off-topic* and cast a down vote to express their disagreement with vi/vim questions being off-topic.  [Voting on meta is different ...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: See Ben's comment https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287089/is-it-appropriate-to-post-vim-questions-on-stack-overflow-now-that-there-is-a-vi?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment160795_287108

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, there's some overlap with vi.se and Stack Overflow given that programmers use Vi/Vim...but this question looks more geared towards specific use of Vim as opposed to something being done in the effort of programming in Vim or programming actual Vimscripts, so I feel like it's on-topic and in a good spot over there, as the OP will get the actual specific kind of help that they're looking for.

Comment: I follow the vim tag, and see a lot of questions regarding the configuration of vim that don't get migrated. Just seems like an inconsistency.

Comment: @HerbWolfe Someone still has to flag a question for migration before it happens.

Comment: @BSMP I'm aware of that. I just don't see the reason it was migrated, as I don't know that I've seen any other vim question migrated, for as long as I've been a member of either site.

Comment: @Herb The scope never changed. Vim has only ever been on-topic insofar as it is related to programming. The fact that you've not witnessed it before does not mean the scope changed. In fact, there have been around 300 Vim questions that got migrated away, and near a thousand that have been closed for non-duplicate reasons.

Comment: The proximate reason that question was migrated was because the person who posted it flagged it and asked that a moderator migrate it. I evaluated the question, determined that it was not obviously programming-related but still looked like a good question, so I migrated it. I agree with what Makoto is saying here, and it is essentially what was already said in [the previous Meta question you linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287089): *"Questions about use of vi from a non-programming aspect though, would not be on topic here.*" Configuring vi is not really programming. @Herb

Comment: @CodyGray Fair enough, I missed that quote when skimming the answer to that previous question.